# C++ should I open a large file for a long time in streaming reading style?

Tags: c++

I need to keep reading data from a very large file in a streaming style (like a database, we keep query data from that file). Is it a good practice to keep that file open, or open it when needed then close every time?

Assume the query is frequent.

If I keep it open, is there anything dangerous I need to pay attention to?

**ADD:**
to clarify my use case:

Only one process will keep query data from that file. The file is about 5GB, and frequency is about 1 time per second, and each query will fetch about 10MB chunk from that file.

The file won't change. We only do reading operation.

Comment: What do you mean by _frequent_? Like, 1000 / second, or like 1 / second

Comment: Is the data in the file changing? If so, what is changing it? You really are not providing enough information for us to provide a useful answer.

Comment: It depends on your particular needs: if your system may have other processes writing to it, you better close it. But if, on the other hand, speed is crucial, and you don't care if someone else needs the file, locking it is a good choice.

Comment: @Simón I've update my use case to be more clear.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've clarified my use case

Comment: Probably, keep it open. Easy to test which is best.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you mean with "streaming style - like a database". On a database, access is usually random.

Closing and re-opening a file every second doesn't seem like making a big difference in performance, but then, if you unnecessarily repeat 1 million times an operation that takes just 1 millisecond, you'll end up wasting 1000 seconds.

Comment: From a security standpoint, I don't see any issues.

Comment: For a question like this, you should say what concerns prompted the question specifically, and and also state all the specific conditions of your "use case". Then people can reply specifically and usefully. I deleted my original answer, because it added no value and was down-voted correctly. By other comments you can see some of the factors to consider and there may be other factors like the Operating System and version you are using.

Comment: @bcperth `you should say what concerns prompted the question specifically` left side of my brain says: Yes, I agree with you. Right side of my brain says: Why do you consider? He just want to learn to do it the best way (to become even more professional). (I understand this intention fully.) The difficulty is that there is in rare cases _one_ best way... :-)

Comment: @Scheff I asked about specific concerns, in case he was worried about something specific, like his file being corrupted or whatever. I am new to SO (the answering side I mean) and open to learning myself!. I understood SO to be for solving specific practical problems and Stack Engineering for **software development methods and practices** where general questions are better tolerated.  Anyhow thanks for feedback!